# Maximum number of records in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I should create a query in SQL Server where I only request a maximum number of records, such as 2000.
The query I use is

```
SELECT * 
FROM [AlarmsHistory] 
WHERE (DATEPART (year, StartTime) = {0}) 
AND (DATEPART (month, StartTime) = {1}) 
AND (DATEPART (day, StartTime) = {2} )
```

where `{0}` I put the year, `{1}` I put the month and `{2}` I put the day.
I might have from 0 also records up to 5000 records. 
What I want is that at most to display 2000 records in a table.

Comment: `select top 2000 ...`

Comment: Check it here, it's very simple: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 2000 * 
FROM [AlarmsHistory] 
WHERE (DATEPART (year, StartTime) = {0}) 
AND (DATEPART (month, StartTime) = {1}) 
AND (DATEPART (day, StartTime) = {2} )
ORDER BY StartTime
```

With TOP you can indicate the max limit of records of query result.

Hope this help.

Comment: PS: I use SQL Server Compact. My query is "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [AlarmsHistory] WHERE (DATEPART(year, StartTime) = 2017) AND (DATEPART(month, StartTime) = 2) AND (DATEPART(day, StartTime) = 20) ORDER BY StartTime"but when I go to do the fill of the 'SqlSeDataAdapter goes wrong: "There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 12,Token in error = 10 ]"

Comment: @fede186 what version of SQL Server Compact ? Try with ..TOP (10) ...(number with brackets)

Answer (score 3):

#### In case of permanent value

You can use TOP 2000 if it is a permanent value. Don't forget about ORDER BY to specify a priority of records to show.

```
SELECT TOP 2000 * 
FROM [AlarmsHistory] 
WHERE (DATEPART (year, StartTime) = {0}) 
    AND (DATEPART (month, StartTime) = {1}) 
    AND (DATEPART (day, StartTime) = {2} )
ORDER BY StartTime DESC -- don't forget about an order, it matters for TOP
```

#### In case if value varies (starts from SQL Server 2012)

Query like for pagination with page number equals 1:

```
DECLARE @PageSize INT = 2000;
DECLARE @PageNumber INT = 1;

SELECT * 
FROM [AlarmsHistory] 
WHERE (DATEPART (year, StartTime) = {0}) 
    AND (DATEPART (month, StartTime) = {1}) 
    AND (DATEPART (day, StartTime) = {2} )
ORDER BY StartTime DESC
OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;
```

Read more about an OFFSET/FETCH here: https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch

#### In case if value varies (version of server is less than SQL Server 2012)

There is no `OFFSET`/`FETCH NEXT`, so use CTE and `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ...)` to give `RowNumber` to each row from a result set, then query for a necessary range. This approach is used for pagination as well in old versions of the SLQ Server, so that I used `@PageSize` and `@PageNumber` variables to show a generic solution. You definitely could shorten it.

```
DECLARE @PageSize INT = 2000;
DECLARE @PageNumber INT = 1;

WITH NumberedRows AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY StartTime DESC) AS RowNumber,
        * 
    WHERE DATEPART(year, StartTime) = {0}
        AND DATEPART(month, StartTime) = {1} 
        AND DATEPART(day, StartTime) = {2}
    FROM [AlarmsHistory]
)
SELECT *
FROM NumberedRows
WHERE RowNumber
    BETWEEN @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) + 1
    AND @PageSize * @PageNumber
```

Comment: Correct, but I think you meant TOP 2000 versus 5000

Comment: If you want to write a really good answer, tell the readers that `TOP` is SQL Server specific, but `OFFSET`/`FETCH NEXT` is ANSI SQL!

Comment: What do you mean? Several dbms products have that syntax.

Comment: @jarlh, I mean that SLQ Server before SQL Server 2012 version does not support the `OFFSET`/`FETCH`

Comment: Yes, I know that.